# Matplotlib legend makes the image too large

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, legend

I'm plotting this figure with matplotlib, the for loop just color the background:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.set_ylabel('Number of contacts')  
ax.set_xlabel('Time [s]') 

for m in range(len(data[node])):
    if data[node][m] == -1:
        ax.axvline(m,color='r',linewidth=5,alpha=0.2,label="OUT")
    if data[node][m] == 0:
        ax.axvline(m,color='g',linewidth=5,alpha=0.2,label="RZ0")
    if data[node][m] == 1:
        ax.axvline(m,color='y',linewidth=5,alpha=0.2,label="RZ1")

ax.plot(x, y, 'b+')
# ax.legend() # HERE is the problem
plt.show()
```

Which plots the following:

[image]

What I want now is a legend to indicate each color of the background meaning, but when I include `ax.legend()` I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Image size of 392x648007 pixels is too large. It must be less than 2^16 in each 
direction.

<Figure size 432x288 with 1 Axes>
<Figure size 432x288 with 0 Axes>
```

How am I supposed to name each color of the background, there are 43200 vertical lines but only 3 colors, does it have anything to do with the number of lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to set the label only once. You can add a variable for each label and replace it with `None` once it's used. Note that using `axvline` to draw a background has the problem that the line width is measured in pixel space, so neighboring lines will either overlap or have a small white space inbetween. Better to use `axvspan`. To avoid the white space at the left and at the right, you can explicitly set the x-limits.

The code can be simplified somewhat using a loop.

Updated code:

- group consecutive spans together for drawing
- precalculate the effect of alpha so the background can be drawn without the need for transparency

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import colors as mcolors
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import itertools

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# create some random data
x = np.arange(100)
y = np.sinh(x/20)
indicators = [-1, 0, 1]
node = 0
data = [np.random.choice(indicators, len(x), p=[10/16,1/16,5/16])]

labels = ["OUT", "RZ0", "RZ1"]
colors = ['lime', 'purple', 'gold']

alpha = 0.4
# precalculate the effect of alpha so the colors can be applied with alpha=1
colors = [[1 + (x - 1) * alpha for x in mcolors.to_rgb(c)] for c in colors]

m = 0
for val, group in itertools.groupby(data[node]):
    width = len(list(group))
    ind = indicators.index(val)
    ax.axvspan(m, m + width, color=colors[ind], linewidth=0, alpha=1, label=labels[ind])
    labels[ind] = None  # reset the label to make sure it is only used once
    m += width

ax.plot(x, y, 'b+')
ax.set_xlim(0, len(data[node]))
ax.legend(framealpha=1) # to make the legend background opaque
plt.show()
```

[image: sample plot]

Comment: It worked, takes a bit long to plot because my df is very large but the image is great. Thanks

Comment: It could be made faster grouping together subsequent spans of the same color. Also, you can use softer colors and leave out the alpha.

Answer (score 1):

Do something like `hrz1 = ax.axvline(m,color='y',linewidth=5,alpha=0.2)` for each of your classes, and then `ax.legend((hrz1, hrz0, hout), ('RZ1', 'RZ0', 'OUT')`.  The `hrz1` pointer will be rewritten for each line you make, and then legend will only make one label for each of the handles.